# TypeScript issue using extends

Tags: typescript

I receive a TypeScript error

when using the follow in code

Error:

Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : string[]'.
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : string[]'.

I would like to have the return type for the function infer using the generic, how to achieve it?

```
console.clear()
function sayHello<T extends string | string[]>(name: T): T extends string ? string : string[] {
    if (typeof name === 'string') {
        return `Hi, ${name}!`;
    } else if (Array.isArray(name)) {
        return name.map(name => `Hi, ${name}!`);
    }
    throw new Error('Invalid value');
}


sayHello('xx')
sayHello(['aa', 'bb'])
```

Error:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzmA2CmA6ECCGAnAFASmAMwFcIQAXAS0gAIpUBPACXlljAB4AVS+ADxPggAmUaiXRkIAc0oAfEWMkBtALoA+TBFQBbeAC5K7bHs48+g4VFHipAfjlXKei-InLKAb2CUvlMnkqYSWgAHeDA-DW1KAF4YygByJys47HdPb3T0eBICdAhKAAN6MgAaSgASNwj4AF8AQnyAbjSvaq5YKHgfP0wAQXR0OkQyKD6B2nUteGwUj3SMrJy8qsRNVCCJyKiVAqLSiqq6-Owm9OrmyhIAC3QwAHdKCHh7gFF+sCw4gEkIADdUWDIAkof1gBHgySaZ2AwBoDCYLEwcW43GSlAA9Gjgf9ATC6IxmGBMAo4qhUHFSnEAEaUuJKFIYrEAgTQoA

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a perfect way to make the compiler not complain about this.
Alternatively, you can use [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

```
function sayHello(name: string): string;
function sayHello(names: string[]): string[];
function sayHello(name: string | string[]) {
  if (typeof name === 'string') {
    return `Hi, ${name}!`;
  } else if (Array.isArray(name)) {
    return name.map((name) => `Hi, ${name}!`);
  }
  throw new Error('Invalid value');
}

const case1 = sayHello('xx');
const case2 = sayHello(['aa', 'bb']);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwIYE8ASBTANruACjFQFtsAuFKAJxjAHMBKK5W+hgbgFgAoUSLAQoMOfERLlkrdowDaAXRbU68hT37ho8JGix4CxMpRUdEAH1NqmiAN59EiGMESEo6AA7Y4LydkQAvEGIAORsqgwhNva8jo402FAgNEgABpgwADSIACS2fgC+AISpGo4FiHjI-s6uAII0NBgAdDDIDU3oRuRM0Q5xCUkpiH7NpKgehN3YNgEAfIjpWbn5xsWpTGWIBf1QABY0cADuI9gnAKKNcDSEIQCSYABuqLgwACaIz7gg2FEaO7w+BAEGxEBBUNUAIyBET6cS3AAeCL+QJBUDBEOwACYYXoxIY5CFUKgQtkQgAjckhJQaIA)

Comment: I think overloading is the correct approach, but it obviates the need for generics. Remove them.

Comment: yes, you are right, I forgot to remove them, thanks for noting!

Answer (score 1):

This is a current limitation of Typescript.

You may learn more here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912